# Security issue with changing Post parameters in form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 application and I am populating a model for an edit form.

```
public class GuestEventModel{

    public String name {get;set;}
    public Int32 GuestID {get;set;}
    public String Address {get;set;}
    public Int32 EventID {get;set;}


}
```

In my form I use `@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.EventID)` and `@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.GuestID)` so in the post back the model has these details populated. I find myself having to repeat code throughout the system to check if the current logged in user can update these Customer details and if the Customer belongs to the event because

1. What is to stop me editing the CustomerID field by changing the source code using inspect element or similar?  This would cause issues where the system will update the wrong customer information against the wrong ID?
2. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very generalized problem and there are many ways to deal with it. but you can simply limit the `Data Access Layer` to fetch only data that is already associated with the user id.

Once the user is successfully authenticated in your system, you should keep the `userId` in the `Session` or encrypted within the `Cookie`, and by no means rely on the client-side to pass the userId.

Then, your `GuestEventModel` could be:

```
public class GuestEventModel
{
    public Int32 UserId { get; set; } // could also be a reference to a 'User' object
    public String name {get;set;}
    public Int32 GuestID {get;set;}
    public String Address {get;set;}
    public Int32 EventID {get;set;}
}
```

Then, anytime you're accessing your Data Layer / Repository:

```
public ActionResult Show(Int32 id)
{
     // assuming you changed your DAL/Repository accordingly
     var guestEvent = dataSource.GetUserEventById(id, Session["userID"] as Int32);

     // or.., assuming your DAL/Repository exposes IQueryable
     var guestEvent = dataSource<GuestEventModel>
                          .Where(x => x.UserId == Session["userID"] as Int32)
                          .Single(x => x.Id == id);

     // ....
     return View(eventViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping a user editing this client-side, as you pointed out.

You don't have to populate it from HTML though. Inside your post method, you can assign the EventID and the GuestID to the model from the server to prevent anyone changing it.

```
public ActionResult SaveEvent(GuestEventModel model) {
   model.EventID = this.Database.GetEventId();
   model.GuestID = this.Database.GetGuestId();
}
```

Comment: Yes but I would need at least one parameter from the model to pass to the GetEventID() and changing this param would effect what is returned from the database also? Plus from the model which param would I use?

Comment: That's up to you and your system requirements. Can you retrieve the user id from the session and the EventID from a URL parameter?